# PyCharm Community change key combinations

Tags: pycharm

Using Mac OS X
I used to be able to type Ctrl+E to go to end of the line in Code Editor, no longer can do it in this version , how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the end of the line of the code by click **⌘ + ]** and you can go to the first of the code line by click **⌘ + [** and you can edit the shortcut from 
**settings / preferences / keymap **